# How did the convention of 'multiplying' using $4\times 3$ become $4\cdot 3$?

Tags: notation, math-history

How did the convention of 'multiplying' using  the cross symbol $4\times 3$ become $4\cdot 3$, using a dot in the middle?

Comment: x looks to much like a $x$ ?

Comment: See also [the similar Question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/when-and-by-whom-were-the-different-symbols-for-multiplication-used) at History of Science and Mathematics (HSM.SE).

Comment: Note, that it often changes further, using juxtaposition so that we use $xy$ to mean $x\cdot y = x\times y$ when it is clear, in the context, what the multiplicative operation is.  E.g., Matrices:  AB means the matrix $A \cdot B$, where the operation is matrix multiplication.  Similarly $3x^2 = 3\cdot x\cdot x$. The symbol $\times$ becomes more useful as representing the Cartesian Product of sets, as cross-product, and by giving dimensions: e.g. a matrix $A_{2\times 2}$, or of a square: $x\times x$, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this originated from Leibniz around 1695 because he thought that you could too easily mistake the multiplying symbol $\times$ for the variable $x$ and he used a point instead. He first used it in a correspondence in 1698.

Answer (score 1):

From [*A Brief History of Algebraic Notation*](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1949-8594.2000.tb17262.x/abstract) by Lynn Stallings:

> Textbook writer William Oughtred...was the first to use the St. Andrew's Cross, $\times$, for multiplication in his 1631 *Clavis Mathimaticae*...Seventeenth century German genius Leibniz criticized Oughtred's use of the cross...because it looked too much like the letter $x$; he suggested the $\cdot$ for multiplication in its place.